# How to use a Vuex store to handle changes during a session?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a `languages` table in my database.

If the admin wants to add a new transport (which has to be translated), I fetch those languages from the database, loop through them, then let the admin fill the form n times  where n = number of languages in the database.

My friend says to use Vuex store so whenever an app launches it fetches languages and saves them in the Vuex store. Then, when an admin changes the route and goes to adding clothes (which need to be translated too), the app doesn't make the call again to show the admin n-th time fillable form.

When the app is launched, let's say we saved 3 languages in the Vuex store and the admin spends 10 minutes on the same page. When they change the page and decide to add clothes, what if in this 10 minutes another admin added a new language?

When the admin changes the route they will get 3 languages and not 4. He says it's good because no need to create a database call, also all the code will be in store at one place (fetching languages, adding languages, editing languages).

How does Vuex handle this scenario where the admin won't see all of the languages?

Comment: Edited for grammar and clarity, reworded question so that it can receive direct answers instead of being open-ended.  Also note that only one question is allowed per post.  Please feel free to post the second question separately.

Comment: @Graham Thats why i just commented because something like that is not possible with Vuex ergo I have no clue how he could solve that with his attempt

Answer (score 0):

Vuex can handle this scenario just fine; it is an app state and data management tool constructed to handle frequent, or not-so-frequent, updates. You are right that Vuex data can fall out of sync with remote data that it is supposed to represent, but it is your job to decide if you want the admin to have, essentially, a live representation of the database, which requires frequent API calls to check for any updates.